# why sklearn aggingRegressor model predict same values?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a 1-d data(1 numpy array). And i want to predict the future data. So I set 0 to 30(float) as x, and the 1-d data as y. now i want to predict the y when x between 30 to 35, i got 5 same outputs.
I tried to use the model to predict the input X, and it seems fit good
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mZoi.png)

I want to know how to predict the true answers. Or someone can teach me how to predict the 1-d data without features.

Comment: Are you looking for time series models? Maybe researching these in python is a good place to start

Comment: yep, i tried prophet model.